# Can´t add = in formula with VBA, Excel

Tags: vba, excel

When I try to make a dynamic formula with VBA in excel i get this error message.

This line is just fine:

```
ActiveCell.Value = "IF(SUM(" & Range("A1:A5").Address & ")*0,1>" & Range("B1").Address & ";" & Range("C1").Address & ";SUM(" & Range("A1:A5").Address & ")*0,1)*-1"
```

If i add = in front of my IF-statement like this, I get the error.

```
ActiveCell.Value = "=IF(SUM(" & Range("A1:A5").Address & ")*0,1>" & Range("B1").Address & ";" & Range("C1").Address & ";SUM(" & Range("A1:A5").Address & ")*0,1)*-1"
```

If i just add the = sign after testing the first code. It runs fine in excel.
What am i doing wrong here?

Don't mind the ranges and stuff. They are only placeholders to make the example as similar to my code as possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To enter a formula in a cell you have to use the `.Formula` property instead of `.Value`.

Try this

`ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(SUM(" & Range("A1:A5").Address & ")*0,1>" & Range("B1").Address & ";" & Range("C1").Address & ";SUM(" & Range("A1:A5").Address & ")*0,1)*-1"`

Comment: I see you are using `,` as a decimal separator and `;` instead of `,`. What happens if you `ActiveCell.FormulaLocal` instead of `ActiveCell.Formula`

Comment: Thank you. Now i just have to figure out how to make it add the sum formula without writing "SUM(" and so on.